# Magento 2 Custom Admin Grid is showing empty page

Tags: magento2, grid

I have create an admin grid in M2, Below is grid ui_component xml file. When I hit the admin url it shows blank page, page source is below as well.

**Grid ui_component xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mastering_items_grid.mastering_items_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mastering_items_grid.mastering_items_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">mastering_items_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="mastering_items_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mastering_items_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <bookmark name="bookmarks" />
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls" />
        <exportButton name="export_button" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext" />
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <paging name="listing_paging" />
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="mastering_items_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mastering_items_grid.mastering_items_grid.mastering_items_columns</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Admin page view source ( Blank page )**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head >
        <script>
    var BASE_URL = 'http://www.magentolocal.com/admin_x1t6kg/mastering/';
    var FORM_KEY = 'tLKrqiMSTIyM2zJl';
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US"
    };
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<title>Magento Admin</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles-old.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css" />
<link  rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<link  rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
            </head>
    <body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "http://www.magentolocal.com/pub/static/version1514629578/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/loader-2.gif"}}' id="html-body" class="mastering-index-index page-layout-1column">
            </body>
</html>
```

**Admin grid layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="mastering_items_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Any Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you linked this in layout xml, please paste your layout xml

Comment: Yes Neo,  Updated question with admin layout xml code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue, it's actually layout defined in admin layout xml file, need to remove that and it works!

**Updated admin grid layout xml ( Removed layout="1column" )**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="mastering_items_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thanks

Comment: 3 hours spent on this, found the solution here. TYVM!

Note: This is why is a VERY BAD IDEA to just copy/paste code from another place u.u

Comment: :D lol, I hope it helped, I spent more then 3 hours when i got same issue.